# is it possible to call browser api's from an iframe injected via webextension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, webextension-polyfill

I am working on a webextension that will inject some ui in some pages. this ui will mostly be inside an iframe to better isolate css.

the problem I have is that I can do `browser` calls from inside the iframe scripts on chrome (I am also using `webextension-polyfill`) but in firefox I get `browser is not defined` error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I doubt this can be answered without [MCVE](/help/mcve). The only unhelpful guess I have so far is that it's one of the many not yet fixed bugs in FF's WebExtension API.

Comment: @wOxxOm I will try to do that. thanks!

Comment: @wOxxOm I think I found an answer! see my response below

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the errors I get are a firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1443253

a relevant comment on the bug page says

> Chrome supports out-of-process frames, so Chrome is able to render an extension frame in an extension process (and the iframe can safely be granted access to extension APIs - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=550151 ).
>   In contrast, Firefox does not support out-of-process frames, so the iframe is handled by a non-extension process (with only limited access to extension APIs).